# Integrating factor in canonical form of second-order linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

In the hyperbolic PDE, I have ticked the part I do not understand. How do they get it to $v_s(r,s)= r-1 + C(s)e^{-r}$ in the canonical form process? In the textbook, it's said that they're using some kind of integrating factor method but there is no further elaboration and I am lost here. Can someone explain all the steps in details?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$(v_s)_r + v_s = r$
is an ordinary differential equation of the variable $r$:
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} + y = r ,
$$
with $y(r,s)=v_s(r,s)$ (the variable $s$ may be viewed as a parameter). This leads to solutions of the form $y=y_p+y_h$, where
$$
y_h(r,s) = C(s) e^{-r}
$$
is the homogeneous solution. The method of variation of parameter suggests to seek a particular solution of the form $y_p(r,s) = C(r,s) e^{-r}$. Finally, one obtains the solutions
$$
v_s(r,s) = r-1+C(s) e^{-r} .
$$